# Passing a groupfunction to Linq query dynamically

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that groups the items in a list based on ID and runs a function such as Min, Max or Average on the values. Please see the code below.

What I want is to be able to pass the function Min, Max or Average etc to this query dynamically. How do we do such a thing using linq?

```
class ZoneValue
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var values = new List<ZoneValue>();

    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "1000", Value = "33" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "1000", Value = "87" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "1000", Value = "29" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "1000", Value = "14" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "2000", Value = "67" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "3000", Value = "33" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "3000", Value = "15" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "3000", Value = "17" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "3000", Value = "67" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "4000", Value = "54" });
    values.Add(new ZoneValue() { Id = "5000", Value = "18" });

    var result = (from zoneValue in values
                  group zoneValue by zoneValue.Id into groupResult
                  select new ZoneValue
                  {
                      Id = groupResult.Key,
                      Value = groupResult.Min(x => Double.Parse(x.Value)).ToString()
                  }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a variable of type `Func<T, TResult>` and pass that to your query:

```
Func<IGrouping<string, ZoneValue>, Double> func;
if(condition) 
    func = group => group.Min(x => Double.Parse(x.Value));
else if(condition2)
    func = group => group.Max(x => Double.Parse(x.Value));
else
    func = group => group.Average(x => Double.Parse(x.Value));
```

Now you use that as follows:

```
var result = (from zoneValue in values
              group zoneValue by zoneValue.Id into groupResult
              select new ZoneValue
              {
                  Id = groupResult.Key,
                  Value = func(groupResult).ToString()
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry but what is Zombi here? and is this syntactically correct? I think the closing angle bracket should be after , Double

Comment: @Aamir Sorry, I ment `ZoneValue`. Updated my answer.